# sliding div while on hover resize

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have for divs enclosed in main div. Parent div is 100% wide, other boxes has equal width, thus 25%. on hover, the div hovered should become wider, other 3 divs equally resized to smaller size.

It is quite working, only when I hover over certain points at edges of parent div, last div slips down. (right top corners, or other points)

I can't find the way out :( 
would be very glad if I'd get some help from you.

here is a working example [jsfiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sthAngels/kmjue/10/)

```
<div class="outer_box">
    <div class="inner_box a">
        <div class="overflow"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner_box b">
        <div class="overflow"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="inner_box c">
        <div class="overflow"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner_box d">
        <div class="overflow"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.outer_box{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    outline:1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.inner_box {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 25%;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
    position:relative;
    background:black;
     -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; 
  -moz-background-clip:    padding; 
  background-clip:         padding-box;
    outline:1px solid white;
}
.first {clear: left;}
.a{background:yellow;}
.b{background:red;}
.c{background:blue;}
.d{background:green;}

.inner_box.hover {  width: 30%;   }
.inner_box.sliding {  width: 23.3%; }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.inner_box').hover(function(){
        //alert('yes');
        $(this).addClass('hover');
        $('.inner_box:not(.hover)').addClass('sliding');

    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
        $('.inner_box').removeClass('sliding');
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me ?

Comment: @adeneo hm - yes, it is difficult to catch the error - sliding down, but it happens at certain points, and can't figure out when exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex way:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/xWc45/3/

```
div.foo {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}

div.foo > div {
    flex: 1;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    transition: flex 350ms;
}

div.foo > div:hover {
    flex: 10;
}

div.foo > div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #f00;
}

div.foo > div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #0f0;
}

div.foo > div:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #00f;
}
```

Other way:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/xWc45/1/

```
div.foo:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

div.foo > div {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    transition: width 350ms;
}

div.foo:hover > div {
    width: 5%;
}

div.foo:hover > div:hover,
div.foo:hover > div:last-child
{
    width: 85%;
}

div.foo:hover > div:hover ~ div
{
    width: 5%;
}
```

Comment: @comma - working really nice, but try to hover at the right corner - all the divs re-stretches to 5%

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use css than jquery... you can use the 'hover' for the effect... here is an example..

for each div specify the width you want to resize to..

```
.the name of first inner div:hover {
width:20px;
transition:1000ms;
}
```

i used ':hover' after the name of the div.. and you can specify the width you want the div to be re sized when hovered.. and 'transition:1000ms;' is used for the slow motion transition effect.. you can change the value to 500 if you like...
hope this helped...

like wise, use this option for each div... and you are good to go :)

Comment: thanks ... basically i did (same have suggested coma - still the issue is the right part, made modification by myself - seems there is a small gap, still causing to not make it work properly. I admit, with css is really much simpler

Comment: If you want to create the sliding effect for both sides, than use jquery... but its simpler to use css to archive what i've shown..
cheers :)

Comment: this was perfectly ok, works like a charm, thanks :) I use jQuery for all other operation on those boxes, it is more than enough